# Raspberry Pi Motion Sensor Random Motion Sensing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi motion sensor to detect when a bird is on a bird feeder outside my house, and then take a photo of it using the Pi Cam. I have had limited success with this, first of all it would work fine, then I got a load of false positives, but crucially I still got the photos I was after, now I am getting completely random results. Some times I will get upwards of 50 triggers an hour sometimes I will get none. I have looked through the photos and there appears to be no connection between any of the differing results. My code is as follows:

```
import time
from picamera import PiCamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)
camera.rotation = 180
camera.exposure_mode = "sports"
print("Sleep...")
sleep(30)
print("Detecting...")

def MOTION(PIR_PIN):
    print("Motion Detected", str(datetime.today()))
    for i in range(4):
        camera.capture("/home/pi/BirdFeedBot/TrainingPhotos/" + str(datetime.today()) + ".jpg")

for i in range(400):
    try:
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING)
        MOTION(PIR_PIN)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Quit")
        GPIO.cleanup()
        camera.close()

GPIO.cleanup()
camera.close()
```

I have seen online a few people getting issues with their USB wifi adapter being too close to the sensor so I have moved it to an external USB hub and is now ~1m away and I have stopped getting regular 2 minute false positives that many people were reporting. Despite this I am still getting very random results, for example I have stood and waved my hand ~20cm from the sensor for a few minutes and yet recieved no trigger, but when there is nothing in front of the sensor, I am still getting false positives.

The motion sensors sensitivity and time delay potentiometers are set to max and min respectively. EDIT: I have also tried two different motion sensor units from different suppliers to rule out a dodgy sensor and gotten the same result.

Any help and guidance is appreciated, thank you and sorry for the long question!

Comment: did you try reducing the sensitivity and increasing the time delay?

Comment: yeah ive tried all sorts of different combinations of the two, Ive also tried a new motion sensor unit from a different supplier (ebay, then PiHut) and gotten the same results

Comment: Is it a PIR sensor? What's the model? Is the sun shining direct on the sensor?

Comment: Yes PIR sensor, https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-pir-motion-sensor-module, the sun occasionally shines into the sensor but it is running all day so the light changes through out the day and no correlation between time and triggers

Comment: Off-topic for SO - most likely you are getting electrical noise on the wire to the sensor triggering your Pi - you could try putting a 10nF(?) ceramic cap on the output from the sensor to stop noise. And/or try a shielded wire with the shield connected to 0V at the Pi. And/or try adding a 10uF electrolytic across the power lines at the sensor. And/or try a much shorter connection and see if the detector appears to triggers less (it's not really triggering).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help will give these steps a go. Cheers.

Comment: Your PIR from PiHut looks like the SR501 which is very sensitive and therefore too many false positives or always high. I found the other PIR AM312 much more stable.  Perhaps you can try your luck with it: "PIR AM312":
https://penzu.com/public/580167ef. Good luck and cheers.